# How could I code a button to call the following JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, jsplumb

I want to use the following button to get JSON data

```
<button>Get JSON data</button>
```

Using this JavaScript

```
    var t = jsPlumbToolkit.newInstance();

    var data = t.exportData({
      type:"myFormat",
      parameters:{
        importantNumber:34,
        somePrefix:"foo-"
      }
    });
```

How could I get the button to call this?

Comment: you could wrap "this" in a function and add an event listener to the button which calls the function that wraps "this" - although, once the button has some JSON (somehow, from "this", by some undisclosed majicks), it won't know what to do with it, because it's just a button

Comment: `$("button").on("click",function() { var t = jsPlumbToolkit.newInstance(); var JSON = t.exportData(); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this in JavaScript. You could start with something as simple as defining a function in javascript and calling it each time the button is clicked:

`<button onclick="get_json_data();">Get JSON data</button>`

```
function get_json_data(){
    var t = jsPlumbToolkit.newInstance();

    var data = t.exportData({
        type:"myFormat",
        parameters:{ importantNumber:34, somePrefix:"foo-" } }
    );
    //Whatever you want to do here
}
```

I stress that maybe this is not the best way of doing this, but it's the easiest to understand. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm, it's saying jsPlumbToolkit is undefined??

Comment: This is just a template for what you want to do. Of course to use jsPlumbToolkit you'd need to import the corresponding files. According to  their [getting started page](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/docs/toolkit/getting-started.html) you need to import a css and two js files in the header of your html.